# D3 v7 Treemap: Zoom Function gets called, but no zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, graph, treemap

I am following this Codepen here, to adapt a Treemap to React and D3.js v7: https://codepen.io/figle/pen/qapRZQ

It works, but as of now it won't zoom in when clicking on nodes. The zoom Function gets called, and I pointed it to the correct element in the pointerClickedEvent - but there is no zooming in.
Can it be that in D3 v7 this behaviour has to be called differently?

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "./KeywordChooser.scss";

// let width = window.innerWidth;
// let height = window.innerHeight;
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
let x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, width]).range([0, width]);
let y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, height]).range([0, height]);
let chart: any;
let nodes: any;
let cells: any;
var parent: any;

function KeywordChooser({ ...treeData }) {
  //   console.log(treeData);
  const [data, setData] = useState(treeData);
  const svgRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(svgRef);

    // Based on: https://codepen.io/figle/pen/qapRZQ

    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(
      d3.schemeDark2.map(function (c: any) {
        c = d3.rgb(c);
        //c.opacity = 0.5;
        return c;
      })
    );

    let treemap = d3
      .treemap()
      .size([width, height])
      //.tile(d3.treemapResquarify) // doesn't work - height & width is 100%
      .paddingInner(0)
      .round(false); //true

    nodes = d3.hierarchy(treeData).sum(function (d) {
      return d.value ? 1 : 0;
    });

    treemap(nodes);

    chart = d3.select(svgRef.current);

    cells = chart
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.descendants())
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", function (d) {
        // console.log(d);
        return "node level-" + d.data.level;
      })
      .attr("title", function (d) {
        return d.data.name ? d.data.name : "null";
      });

    cells
      .style("left", function (d) {
        return x(d.x0) + "%";
      })
      .style("top", function (d) {
        return y(d.y0) + "%";
      })
      .style("width", function (d) {
        return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) + "%";
      })
      .style("height", function (d) {
        return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0) + "%";
      })
      //.style("background-image", function(d) { return d.value ? imgUrl + d.value : ""; })
      //.style("background-image", function(d) { return d.value ? "url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300)" : "none"; })
      .style("background-color", function (d) {
        while (d.level > 2) d = d.parent;
        return color(d.data.name);
      })
      .on("click", zoom)
      .append("p")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.name ? d.data.name : "---";
      });
    //.style("font-size", "")
    //.style("opacity", function(d) { return isOverflowed( d.parent ) ? 1 : 0; });

    parent = d3.select(".up").datum(nodes).on("click", zoom);
  }, [treeData]);

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <div className="up">&larr; UP</div>
      </nav>
      <div className="feature" id="chart" ref={svgRef}></div>
    </>
  );
}

function zoom(d) {
  // http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/amszcymq/
  // console.log(d);

  console.log(
    "clicked: " +
      d.target.__data__.data.name +
      ", level: " +
      d.target.__data__.data.level
  );

  let currentLevel = d.target.__data__.data.level;
  // console.log(currentLevel);
  parent.datum(d.target.__data__.parentNode || nodes);

  x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
  y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

  var t = d3.transition().duration(800).ease(d3.easeCubicOut);

  cells
    .transition(t)
    .style("left", function (d) {
      return x(d.x0) + "%";
    })
    .style("top", function (d) {
      return y(d.y0) + "%";
    })
    .style("width", function (d) {
      return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) + "%";
    })
    .style("height", function (d) {
      return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0) + "%";
    });

  cells // hide this level and above
    .filter(function (d) {
      return d.ancestors();
    })
    .classed("hide", function (d) {
      return d.target.__data__.children ? true : false;
    });

  cells // show this level + 1 and below
    .filter(function (d) {
      return d.target.__data__.data.level > currentLevel;
    })
    .classed("hide", false);
}

export default KeywordChooser;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!